# Exception in createprocessasuser - JclMiscel

Tags: delphi, jedi

I need to execute some EXE with specific user. So I used `CreateProcAsUser` function JclMiscel under JCL Library. but when I run my code i`ll get run-time exception. here it is

> exception class EjdError with message 'NT version 3.51 build 1057 or
>   later required'

here is my Code

```
var
  Command2, TemExtractPath, x,TargetDirectory: String;
begin
  try
    TemExtractPath := 'C:\MtntopDispense\Updates\HICOnline\temp';
    TargetDirectory := 'D:\Test';
    Command2 := 'Robocopy "' + TemExtractPath + '" "' + TargetDirectory +
      '" /MIR /dcopy:T';
    CreateProcAsUser('.', 'nexusdb', 'mtntop', Command2);

  except
    on E: Exception do

      ShowMessage(E.StackTrace + '-' + E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Apparently, a function used by CreateProcAsUser was not available prior to the OS version specified in the message. This is a very old version though, so I doubt that is the actual issue. What is "System.SysUtils.Win32BuildNumber" on your machine?

Comment: This exception is raised by the first line of `CreateProcAsUser`, which calls `CheckOSVersion`, which raises the exception. So what version of Windows are you running your code on?

Comment: Wrong JCL tag, I think. Removing. There are some specifics which should come up if you type jcl in the tag area.

Comment: I`m using Windows 10

Comment: NT 3.51 is pre Win95, so that really is not the issue. Again, what is the Win32BuildNumber? The JCL code uses this variable to check, so the issue has to be there somewhere.

Comment: Win32BuildNumber is '0'

Comment: That means the routine to set this value is either not called or faulty. What Delphi version do you run? Try inspecting the TOSVersion record to see what it returns for Major, Minor & Build.